# Using lapply to generate new variables across data sets, conditional on not existing

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, lapply

Let's say I have three data sets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3), var3 = c(1,2,3))
```

I would like to check to see if a variable "var3" exists within each dataset. If it doesn't, I would like to generate an empty variable called "var3". Here is what I am trying:

```
dframes <- list(df1,df2,df3)

lapply(dframes, function(df) { 
   ifelse("var3" %in% colnames(df), print("var3 exists"), df$var3 <- NA)
})
```

The output comes out as:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] "var3 exists"
```

And the desired "var3" variable isn't generated for the first two data sets - they still only contain "var1" and "var2".

You're help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `return(df)` to your function

Comment: You don't need `return`, just `df` will suffice. Also, your `print` function won't be too informative if you want to save those results somewhere, as `lapply` isn't updating your data sets, rather prints the desired results.

Comment: Many thanks @DavidArenburg and @MaratTalipov . If I wanted the results to update the data set, how would I do this? 

I tried `df <- as.data.frame(df)`, but the stored data sets remain the same.

Comment: @muadhib Perhaps I'm missing something, but why wouldn't you just do `dframes <- lapply(dframes...)` to update your dframes?

Comment: @MaratTalipov I want to adjust `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, rather than the list `dframes`. I don't think I understand when to use `lapply` over a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting what everyone has said into a full answer:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(1,2,3), var3 = c(1,2,3))

dframes <- list(df1,df2,df3)

dfframes_fmt <- lapply(dframes, function(df) { 
  if(! "var3" %in% colnames(df)) {
    df$var3 <- NA
  }
  df
})

> dfframes_fmt
[[1]]
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1   NA
2    2    2   NA
3    3    3   NA

[[2]]
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1   NA
2    2    2   NA
3    3    3   NA

[[3]]
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3
```

In order to update to the original names, you can do this:

```
dfnames <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
# assemble the list of data frames
dframes <- eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", paste0(dfnames, collapse = ","), ")")))

for(k in seq_along(dframes)){
  set <- dframes[[k]]
  if(! "var3" %in% colnames(set)) {
    set$var3 <- NA
  }
  # assign the df back to the original name
  eval(parse(text =  paste0(dfnames[k], " = set")))
}


> df1
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1   NA
2    2    2   NA
3    3    3   NA
> df2
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1   NA
2    2    2   NA
3    3    3   NA
> df3
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3
```

Comment: Would you mind adding in a line that would update the data sets `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, rather than just outputting results? Thanks again, @mkemp6.

Comment: @mkempf6 This is great. I would have had a lot of trouble coming up with this. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem! Would you mind accepting it as the answer if it has answered your question as you intended?

Comment: Done. @mkempf6 I did want to follow-up. I am getting thrown an error when I plug in your code:


`Error: unexpected string constant in:
"  # assign the df back to the original name
  eval(parse(text =  paste0(dframes[[k]] " = set""
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}" `

I just copy and pasted.

Comment: @muadhib sorry about that, missed a comma, it is fixed above.